# __doPostBack triggers Microsoft JScript runtime error: Access is denied

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

I have this javascript code:

```
    function checkUploadedFile() {
        var inputFile = $("#fuUploadProfile").val();
        if (inputFile != "") {
            __doPostBack('btnUploadProfile', '');
        } else {
            $("#lblMessage").show();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

here are the controls:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" CssClass="srn_error">*Required</asp:Label>
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuUploadProfile" runat="server" CssClass="srn_file" />    
<asp:Button ID="btnUploadProfile" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Upload" class="srn_button" OnClientClick="checkUploadedFile();" />
```

Even though I already have selected a file to upload, I get the "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Access is denied." only when using IE9.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This seems to cause the same error in IE 10 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after much thorough searching of the code, it was due to a javascript that was loaded, which was triggering the 'click' event of the asp.net FileUpload control. it seems that IE does not play well with javascript events that trigger a DOM control.

after I disabled the javascript function, it was working perfectly.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer so others can see that it's been answered.

Comment: But what if the javascript event that trigger the button (in my case, the submit button) is needed for the form to work?